# Ajax call to take longitude and latitude from IP address

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, ip, ip-address

how would you do an Ajax call, using an IP address to request latitude and longitude

Also include what parameters would be needed, like which url can I request to?

Note, I am unable to use plugins

Answer (score 1):

jqlpLocation is a jQuery plugin made for exactly this. I would recommend reading up on it and seeing if it will suit your needs.

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/09/get-ip-address-information-using-jquery.html